# Получение Json и Python (на примере PHP

Tags: php, python, json

Доброго времени суток. Работаю с VK API, имеется JSON строка с которой мне нужно вытащить кое какие значения.

В PHP это делалось легко:

```
  $url = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.search?q=bla-bla&access_token=<TOKEN>");
    $data = json_decode($url,true);  

        foreach ($data['response'] as $item) {
    $photo = $item['attachment']['photo']['src_big'];
    echo $photo
    }
```

Пытаюсь сделать по аналогии на Питоне:

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
import json
url = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-bla-bla&"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
a = data['response']['attachment']['photo']['src_big']

print(a)
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
a = data['response']['attachment']['photo']['src_big']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Максимум что я могу сделать, так это получить все доступные поля:

```
.......
a = data['response']

for b in a:
    print(b)
```

Как мне записать в переменную `a = data['response']['attachment']['photo']['src_big']` ?

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php код содержит foreach цикл, который вы забыли в Питон коде:

```
with urlopen(url) as response:
    data = json.load(response)
    for item in data['response']:
        photo = item['attachment']['photo']['src_big']
        print(photo)
```

> Спасибо за ответ! Сделал так как вы сказали, в итоге получил ошибку TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

TypeError показывает, что item это целое число в этом случае—php код также обязан ломаться в этом случае: [`$item['attachment']` возвращает NULL для типов, которые индексацию не придерживают](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25734975/4279).

В Питоне не принято игнорировать ошибки молча, если они явно не подавлены. Из [The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

> Errors should never pass silently.
>   Unless explicitly silenced.

Вы можете использовать try/except, чтобы проигнорировать TypeError или использовать в теле цикла:

```
if isinstance(item, int):
    continue
```

Код переходит на следующий цикл если item число.

Если `print(data['response'])` показывает или документация vk api для вашего запроса гарантирует какую-то определённую структуру возвращаемых данных, то можно точнее код написать.

К примеру, если вас интересует только второй элемент из возвращаемого списка, то не нужно for-цикл использовать:

```
item = data['response'][1]
photo = item['attachment']['photo']['src_big']
print(photo)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Сделал так как вы сказали, в итоге получил ошибку `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @ВладимирВ. Код делает то же что и php. Напечатайте, каждый item и сравните с тем что в php получаете. Если слишком много данных, то используйте последовательно item, item['attachment'], item['attachment']['photo'] пока разницу не увидите.

Comment: в том то и дело, как только я начинаю писать item['attachment'], item['attachment']['photo']  я получаю одну и ту же ошибку `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`   Если оставлю просто `photo = item` то выводится просто список json

Comment: @ВладимирВ. Какая строчка к ошибке ведёт? item[a] или item[a][b]? Покажите item. Какой вывод php в таком случае даёт? В чём разница? Кстати, print(item) не печатает json (он выводит текстовое представление Питон объектов, которое может быть похоже, но отличается—к примеру Питон использует одинарные кавычки в таких случаях).

Comment: Какой бы я item[a], item[a][b], item[a][b][c] не пытался вывести, ошибка будет ругаться на этот же Item `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`....  да, при выводе просто item питон выводит текстовое представление питон объектов с одинарными кавычками.  в РНР при запросе `item['attachment']['photo']['src_big']` я получаю простую ссылку `http:\\site.ru\img.jpg`

Comment: @ВладимирВ. Ещё раз: покажите `print(item)` для item, который TypeError вызывает при индексировании (ошибка говорит, что item это целое число в этом случае—php код также обязан ломаться в этом случае: `$item['attachment']` возвращает NULL в этом случае.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечаю сам на свой же вопрос. Методом тыка у меня получилось добиться желаемого результата. Правда не до конца понимаю почему в цикле `for` у меня получилось вывести значения через `vapi` а не через `vphoto` как должно быть по логике.

Но в целом код рабочий, может быть пригодится таким же как и я, новичкам в Python.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

url = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?owner_id=-bla-bla"

data = urlopen(url)
decoded_response = data.read().decode()
final_data = json.loads(decoded_response)
vapi = final_data['response'][1:]
for vphoto in vapi:
    print(vapi[0]["attachment"]['photo']['src_big'])
```

P.S. можно конечно было использовать библиотеку vk `pip install vk`, но и без нее все работает

Comment: Совершенств бессмысленно for-цикл здесь использовать, если вы только vapi[0]... печатаете . Я [обновил ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/614392/23044)